# Flutter build Appbundle Error:* What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This is the error that I'm getting when I'm trying to run "flutter build appbundle" in terminal.
I already search for some solution but none of it has the same error as I get

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\User_Name\Desktop\deploy\bahetra\android\app\build.gradle' line: 31
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Malformed \uxxxx encoding.

This is the code from my "android\app\build.gradle":

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile)) // line 31
   }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.bahetra"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The issue is in key.properties file. Replace all the backslash in the store location with the forward slash and it should work. Eg:

Update this in key.properties file:

```
storeFile= C:\Users\<user name>\upload-keystore.jks
```

to this:

`storeFile=C:/Users/<user name>/upload-keystore.jks`

Comment: Thanks a lot this answer saved me

Comment: Struggled for hours before finding this. Seriously flutter needs to update their documentation

Comment: Even after this now I have brand new errors `Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.`

Comment: I tried this and I got a wakelock error

Comment: This one was an extra frustrating issue as the Flutter documentation refrences back slashes. `C:\\Users\\<user name>\\upload-keystore.jks`

Comment: the second time I go to this answer , thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

just replace the backslash to forward-slash in key.properties in storeFile

before

```
storeFile=<location>\upload-keystore.jks
```

after

```
storeFile=<location>/upload-keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the key.properties file. The store location contains backslashes, which need to be replaced with forward slashes. This will fix the issue. For example,

Update this in key.properties file:

```
storeFile= C:\Users\<user name>\upload-keystore.jks
```

to this:

```
storeFile=C://Users//<user name>//upload-keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 0):

in key.properties file:
must
storeFile=C:\Users\\upload-keystore.jks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First of run terminal as Run As Administrator and than

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore upload-keystore.jks -storepass %password% -validity 360 -keysize 2048
```

%password% is your password